# Direct Comparison Test: Choosing a Test Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine if $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{i!}{i^i}$ converges using the Direct Comparison Test.

**Answer**: Since
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{i!}{i^i} & = & \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots i}{i\cdot i\cdot i\cdots i} \\
\frac{i!}{i^i} & = & \frac{1}{i}\cdot\frac{2}{i} \cdot\frac{3}{i} \cdots \frac{i}{i} \\
\frac{i!}{i^i} & \leq & \frac{1}{i}\cdot\frac{2}{i} \\
\frac{i!}{i^i} & \leq & \frac{2}{i^2} \\
a_i & \leq & b_i
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{i^2}$ is a convergent $p$-series and $a_i \leq b_i$, then the given series converges by the Direct Comparison Test.

However, my concern is why in the approximation are only the terms $\frac{1}{i}\cdot\frac{2}{i}$ selected? If we take three or four, then the test series will still be convergent. If we take only one, the test series will be divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we take only one, the test series will be divergent.

Right. This leads to a vacuous upper bound $\sum_i \frac{i!}{i^i} \le \sum_i \frac{1}{i} = \infty$ and does not provide any information.

> If we take three or four, then the test series will still be convergent.

Sure, those would be alternate valid ways of proving the convergence of your original series.